# tikz hatched rectangle auto-pst-pdf conflict

Tags: tikz-pgf, auto-pst-pdf

I am trying to get tikz to work with `auto-pst-pdf`, but the hatched rectangle I am drawing is generated correctly only if I remove the package `auto-pst-pdf` from the preamble. I really need these two to work since I am using this package in the main code with `psfrag`.

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=blue] (0,0) rectangle (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If I use `auto-pst-pdf`, the output is just a rectangle filled completely with black color. If I remove the package, the output is as expected.

I must mention that lines, circles, etc are working ok with both packages loaded.

Comment: Isn't `auto-pst-pdf` cone to work with `pstricks` and friends?

Comment: Here, your MWE works fine with `pdflatex --shell-escape myFile.tex`. What distribution are you running ?

Comment: can you check in another viewer ? And you should really consider not using psfrag.Don't tell David Carlisle I said this

Comment: I use MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.4902 (1.40.14) (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit). I enabled --shell-escape under Execution Modes -> pdfLaTeX -> Switches. @percusse: what should I use if I want to replace eps text with latex text?

Comment: @marsupilam I ran your code in cmd, and also get wrong result

Comment: @percusse As viewer, I used Adobe and SumatraPDF. In Adobe it is completely blank, in Sumatra its a black rectangle

Answer (score 1):

With an up-to-date TL2017 there is no problem, with or without `auto-pst-pdf` (xelatex and pdflatex)

[image]